# VS Code does not show output from a program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I've created a c++ project on ubuntu in visual studio code.
It launches the program using gdb mode, but does not show anything in Output. When I launch program from console, the output is present. I tried inserting "console" property, but vscode tells me, that it is forbidden (from similar issue with node https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30842).

How can I enable vscode to show the output from my program?

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",            
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You config is correct. The program output should be in the **DEBUG CONSOLE**.

**Menu | Debug Console** or **Ctrl+Shift+Y**.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not show the data, that program outputs to cout. Just the gdb data. And debugging works correctly - it stops on breakpoints, etc. Maybe it is not possible to achieve printing program output with gdb?

Comment: Thanks, I found the terminal window.

Comment: Why does it give output in the debug console? How do I shift it to the integrated one? Also, how do I handle input(cin) for debugging? I don't think i can give input in the debug console

Comment: @JatinSharma You can. Don't think, just try.

Comment: for me it was in the terminal window under "cppdbg: (programname)". Odd because i'm used to the output being under Debug Console under lldb, but there it is.

Answer (score 1):

The program was launched in external terminal and due to the configuration of my screen I didn't see it. Everything works fine.

Comment: Is such behavior on Windows?

Comment: No, I'm using Ubuntu with Unity. Did not try in Windows.

Comment: can you elaborate ? how did you access your config ? what parameters had you have to change ?

Answer (score -2):

Add this line in setting.json in code-runner.executorMap

```
"cpp": "g++ -o $fileNameWithoutExt $fileNameWithoutExt.cpp && ./$fileNameWithoutExt"
```

Comment: Please add further context to your answer.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This is NOT a solution. It will mess up the debug mode, because debug mode will also execute these commands of `args`.